# Sie hat braune Haare

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending

When I was studying German, I saw the following sentence:

> Sie hat braune Haare.

The word "Haar" has neutral article and it is the object of the sentence. According to "German adjective ending reference tables" I checked out, it should have taken "es" not "e" because there are not any articles in the sentence and the object is in accusative form. However, it did not. Could someone explain why?

P.S: My German is very limited. Could you please explain it in English as much as possible.

Comment: It's the same with `Informationen` which is uncountable in English, too. A counter example is `pants` where Germans scratch their head why one item is plural already.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could say either

> Sie hat braune Haare.

or

> Sie hat braunes Haar.

In the former, "Haare" is plural (which seems fitting, given that she has about 100000 single hairs on her head), whereas in the latter, "Haar" is singular and refers to the collective of hair(s) as a whole (similar to "Fell" (fur)) and uncountable.

Note that with some other adjectives, *only* the second form is commonly used, e.g.,

> Sie hat volles Haar.

Comment: Note that while *Sie hat braune Haare* is not uncommon in German, the literal translation, "She has brown hairs", would never be used in English.

Comment: Also possible: _ihr Haar ist braun_ or _ihre Haare sind braun_ and _sie ist brünett_.

Comment: »Sie hat volle Haare« klingt ein bisschen, als hätte sie in Wodka geduscht ;)